# Create outliers column in pandas groupby DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, pandas-groupby, pandas-apply

I have a very large pandas DataFrame with several thousand codes and the cost associated with each one of them (sample):

```
data = {'code': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
        'cost': [10, 20, 100, 10, 10, 500, 10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I am creating a `groupby` object at the `code` level, i.e.,:

```
grouped = df.groupby('code')['cost'].agg(['sum', 'mean']).apply(pd.Series)
```

Now I really need to add a new column to this `grouped` DataFrame, determining the percentage of codes that have outlier costs. My initial approach was this external function (using `iqr` from `scipy`):

```
def is_outlier(s):
    # Only calculate outliers when we have more than 100 observations
    if s.count() >= 100:
        return np.where(s >= s.quantile(0.75) + 1.5 * iqr(s), 1, 0).mean()
    else:
        return np.nan
```

Having written this function, I added `is_outlier` to my `agg` arguments in the `groupby` above. This did not work, because I am trying to evaluate this `is_outlier` rate for every element in the `cost` series:

```
grouped = df.groupby('code')['cost'].agg(['sum', 'mean', is_outlier]).apply(pd.Series)
```

I attempted to use `pd.Series.where` but it does not have the same functionality as the `np.where`. Is there a way to modify my `is_outlier` function that has to take the `cost` series as argument in order to correctly evaluate the outliers rate for each code? Or am I completely off-path?

**UPDATE** Desired Result (minus the minimum observations requirement for this example):

```
>>> grouped

  code    sum    mean    is_outlier

0  'a'    110     55     0.5
1  'b'    20      20     0
2  'c'    530     132.5  0.25
```

Note: my sample is terrible in order for me to calculate outliers since I have 2, 1, and 4 observations respectively for each `code`. In the production data frame each code has hundreds or thousands of observations, each one with a cost associated. In the sample result above, the values for `is_outlier` mean that, for `'a'` one out of the two observations has a cost in the outlier range, for `'c'` one out of the four observations has a cost in the outlier range, etc - I am trying to recreate this in my function by assigning 1's and 0's as the result of `np.where()` and taking the `.mean()` of that

`.apply(pd.Series)` is needed in order to cast the `<pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy object> resulting from`groupby`into a DataFrame.`s`is a pandas Series with all values of`cost`for each`code`, as generated from the`groupby`operation (`split`phase of`split-apply-combine`)

Comment: Please show desired result and how how you are running the *is_outlier* method and `apply(pd.Series)` is redundant. What is *s* argument? Entire dataframe?

Comment: @Parfait I just edited my question to explain

Comment: Checking outlier across both *sum* and *mean* columns?

Comment: No, checking whether each individual row's `cost` is an outlier with respect to this `code`'s cost distribution, and then coming up with a single outlier rate per cost. For example, for `code 'c'` there are 4 observations: 10, 10, 500, 10. There is one outlier (500), so for `code 'c'` the `is_outlier` column has to have a value of `0.25` (1 of 4 observations)

Answer (score 0):

## Data used

```
# Loading Libraries
import pandas as pd;
import numpy as np;

# Creating Data set
data = {'code': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'a'],
    'cost': [10, 20, 200, 10, 10, 500, 10, 10, 10, 10]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

## Defining a function for calculating the proportion of outliers in a specified column

```
def outlier_prop(df,name,group_by):

    """
    @Packages required
    import pandas as pd;
    import numpy as np;

    @input
    df = original dataframe
    name = This is the name column for which you want the dummy list
    group_by = column to group by

    @output
    data frame with an added column 'outlier' containing the proportion of outliers
    """

    # Step 1: Create a dict of values for each group
    value_dict = dict()
    for index,i in enumerate(df[group_by]):
        if i not in value_dict.keys():
            value_dict[i] = [df[name][index]]
        else:
            value_dict[i].append(df[name][index])

    # Step 2: Calculate the outlier value for each group and store as a dict
    outlier_thres_dict = dict()
    unique_groups = set(df[group_by])
    for i in unique_groups:
        outlier_threshold = np.mean(value_dict[i]) + 1.5*np.std(value_dict[i])
        outlier_thres_dict[i] = outlier_threshold

    # Step 3: Create a list indicating values greater than the group specific threshold
    dummy_list = []
    for index,i in enumerate(df[group_by]):
        if df[name][index] > outlier_thres_dict[i]:
            dummy_list.append(1)
        else:
            dummy_list.append(0)

    # Step 4: Add the list to the original dataframe
    df['outlier'] = dummy_list

    # Step 5: Grouping and getting the proportion of outliers
    grouped = df.groupby(group_by).agg(['sum', 'mean']).apply(pd.Series)

    # Step 6: Return data frame
    return grouped
```

## Calling the function

```
outlier_prop(df, 'cost', 'code')
```

## Output

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/magoavi/stackoverflow/master/50533570.png